# xlib и astra linux

Tags: linux, x11, xlib

при выборе определенного окна приложения через программу оно должно разворачиваться на весь экран. взял за основу libX. Написал некий код:

```
void WindowManager::maximizeWindow(unsigned long win) {
    Display* disp = XOpenDisplay(nullptr);
    XEvent ev;
    ev.xclient.window = win;
    ev.xclient.type = ClientMessage;
    ev.xclient.format = 32;
    ev.xclient.message_type = XInternAtom(disp, "_NET_WM_STATE", False);
    ev.xclient.data.l[0] = 1;
    ev.xclient.data.l[1] = static_cast<long>(
        XInternAtom(disp, "_NET_WM_STATE_MAXIMIZED_HORZ", False));
    ev.xclient.data.l[2] = static_cast<long>(
        XInternAtom(disp, "_NET_WM_STATE_MAXIMIZED_VERT", False));
    ev.xclient.data.l[3] = 1;
    XSendEvent(
        disp,
        DefaultRootWindow(disp),
        False,
        SubstructureRedirectMask | SubstructureNotifyMask,
        &ev);
    XCloseDisplay(disp);
}
```

**Результат:**

**Debian 10:** Работает как положено, разворачивается на весь экран как и задумывалось.

**Astra Linux:** Окно становится активным, но не разворачивается на весь экран и так и остаётся "свёрнутым". может есть какие-то особенности и финты, которые я не предусмотрел?

Comment: Программирование на голых иксах может быть забавным аттракционом. Лучше возьмите Qt и сберегите себе нервы.

Comment: у них там по умолчанию вместо window manager используется некая собственная программа под названием flywm. скажем так, несколько специфичная программа.

Comment: Qt это хорошо) возможно и правда получится интегрировать к себе. flywm, интересно, спасибо